# Data loading in Oracle db table

Tags: sql, linux, oracle

I have data of approx. 110 million in text file. What is the fastest way to load this data in Oracle db table as I am using sqlloader which took around 34 hrs to completely load in table.

Comment: Please don't use local measurements, they will just confuse people. And what is "110 million data". Bytes? Rows? Something else?

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also see questions like [Why are SQL server inserts so slow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1743496/608639), [SQL speed up performance of insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7090243/608639), [Fastest way to insert a million rows in Oracle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18414529/608639), etc.

Answer (score 1):

`sqlloader` is **the** tool to use to load data in an Oracle table. If I correctly remember, and if you can trust the input data, possible optimizations are:

- tweak the buffer size and number of lines per commit. The less commits will be the fastest at the price of more memory
- drop the indexes before loading data and re-create them after - risk: if a data violates a unique or non null index you lose, but gain can be one order of magnitude
- if it makes sense and again if you can trust the input data, disable any trigger on the table - risk: same as previous line